# implement a simple search bar in express node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

so i've tried to implement a simple search functionality to practice,

my goal is to have the url "/search/(parameter here)" and get the product who's name matches the parameter.

this is my middleware:

```
router.get('/search/:title', function(req, res, next) {
    var title = req.params.title;
    Product.find({title: title}, function (err, products) {
        if(err) {
            res.render('shop/search', {products: null});
        }
        res.render('shop/search', {products: products});
        next();
    });
});
```

i don't know why, but it gives me the error:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

i can't see why i get this, it says i'm changing headers, i'm kind of new to this and i'm not sure where do i change headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call the next middleware ( i.e `next()` ) after rendering the response to the client, you should remove it, also use `return` statement in order to stop the remaining code from executing, here is the correct syntax:

```
router.get('/search/:title', function(req, res, next) {
    var title = req.params.title;
    Product.find({title: title}, function (err, products) {
        if(err) {
            return res.render('shop/search', {products: null});
            ^^^^^^
        }
        res.render('shop/search', {products: products});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

res.render(..) can only be called once for a request. Therefore you should add an else statement as follows:

```
if(err)
    res.render('shop/search', {products: null});
else
    res.render('shop/search', {products: products});
```