# How to pass database values from node js to ejs file

Tags: node.js, search, ejs

Hi I am trying to add search bar in main page and search in the main page without changing to another page.
My user.js file

```
                       if (req.method == 'get'){
                            var username = req.query.username;
                            Users.find({username}, function (err, user)  {
                                if(err) {
                                    return res.render(template:'index')
                                }
                                res.render({template:'index', { user : user}});
                            })
                        }
```

my index.ejs file

```
<div class="search-user">   
    <% for user in user { %>
        <div>
            <p>Username : <%= user.username %></p>
            <p>Age <%= user.age %></p>
            <p>Status <%= user.status %></p>
        </div>
    <% } %>     
</div>
```

This is giving me errors. May i know what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a console message and check if you are getting data in user object

```
if (req.method == 'get'){
                            var username = req.query.username;
                            Users.find({username}, function (err, user)  {
                                if(err) {
                                    console.log('error', error)
                                    return res.render('index')
                                }
                                console.log('user', user)
                                res.render('index', { user });
                            })
                        }
```

Further before iterating user of object just check something like this:

```
<div>
   <p>Username : <%= JSON.stringfy(user) %></p>
 </div>
```

By this you will get to know where error is being occured.

Comment: Thanks. I can see where is error happening with console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Res.render()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render)

```
                       if (req.method == 'get'){
                            var username = req.query.username;
                            Users.find({username}, function (err, user)  {
                                if(err) {
                                    return res.render('index')
                                }
                                res.render('index', { user });
                            })
                        }
```

Comment: Unexpected identifier in ...index.ejs while compiling ejs If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint: https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.500

Comment: i am having this error when i add div class in ejs file. Do you know why?

Comment: did you set in your app.js? this is assuming index.ejs is inside `views` directory
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Comment: yes it is inside views/home/index.ejs.so is it inside of my app.js app.set('views', home/index.ejs + '/views': app.set('view engine', 'ejs') ??                                                                                                 please dont mind me. i want to make sure i am correct.

Comment: in that case, use as follows: app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/home');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Comment: can you try with removing `<% for user in user { %>`?

Comment: and it says <%= user.username %><%= user.age %><%= user.status %> are not defined.

Comment: what is the result of user here Users.find({username}, function (err, user)  {...})

Comment: i cannot check the result and i follow that one from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589441/implement-a-simple-search-bar-in-express-node-js this